# Web Server The connection has timed out everyday

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04

Recently, my web server cannot be access. It give me
The connection has timed out.
The server at IP_ADDRESS is taking too long to respond.

Server reboot fix the problem. but the problem appear the everyday.

The server is Ubuntu 12.04 with Apache/2.2.22 and I use Wordpress for the content.

When the problem occured, I've tried restart the apache2 service, but no use.
When i check the log using tail -f and try to open the web page, there is no updated log.
I've try 
I've tried telnet IP_ADDRESS http from client, it failed to connect. After the reboot, it's success.

I still have no clue on what is the cause of that problem. Please help me.

Below is what i captured when the problem is occured at 7 Oct.

cat /proc/meminfo

```
MemTotal:        4047288 kB
MemFree:         3397704 kB
Buffers:           57232 kB
Cached:           391364 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           394736 kB
Inactive:         153000 kB
Active(anon):      99180 kB
Inactive(anon):      300 kB
Active(file):     295556 kB
Inactive(file):   152700 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       4191228 kB
SwapFree:        4191228 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         99136 kB
Mapped:            21556 kB
Shmem:               344 kB
Slab:              52572 kB
SReclaimable:      37588 kB
SUnreclaim:        14984 kB
KernelStack:        1104 kB
PageTables:         4020 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     6214872 kB
Committed_AS:     542004 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      142668 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359569356 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       63424 kB
DirectMap2M:     4130816 kB
```

netstat -an

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 IPADDRESS:53      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 IPADDRESS:53      0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*
```

syslog

```
Oct  7 07:09:01 web CRON[8762]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Oct  7 07:17:01 web CRON[8816]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct  7 07:39:01 web CRON[8914]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Oct  7 08:09:01 web CRON[9062]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Oct  7 08:17:01 web CRON[9116]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct  7 08:39:01 web CRON[9214]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Oct  7 08:49:20 web named[896]: error (network unreachable) resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53
Oct  7 08:49:20 web named[896]: error (network unreachable) resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53
Oct  7 09:09:01 web CRON[9880]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
```

ps aux

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  24344  2280 ?        Ss   Oct06   0:01 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [migration/0]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [rcuob/0]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [rcuob/1]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [rcuob/2]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [rcuob/3]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:02 [rcu_sched]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:01 [rcuos/0]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:02 [rcuos/1]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [rcuos/2]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [rcuos/3]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [watchdog/1]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [migration/1]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [kworker/1:0]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [watchdog/2]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [migration/2]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [kworker/2:0]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [kworker/2:0H]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [watchdog/3]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [migration/3]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [kworker/3:0H]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [khelper]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [netns]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [writeback]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [bioset]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [kworker/u9:0]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [kblockd]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [khubd]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [md]
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:35 [kworker/0:1]
root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [kswapd0]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Oct06   0:00 [ksmd]
root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Oct06   0:00 [khugepaged]
root        52  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [crypto]
root        66  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        67  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [kworker/2:1]
root        69  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:02 [kworker/3:1]
root        70  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        71  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root        73  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [dm_bufio_cache]
root        93  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [deferwq]
root        94  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [charger_manager]
root        95  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:01 [kworker/1:1]
root       208  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [mpt_poll_0]
root       209  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [mpt/0]
root       250  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       263  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [jbd2/sda1-8]
root       264  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root       265  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [ext4-unrsv-conv]
root       377  0.0  0.0  17372   636 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root       404  0.0  0.0  21660  1432 ?        Ss   Oct06   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
103        416  0.0  0.0  23928   992 ?        Ss   Oct06   0:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart
syslog     420  0.0  0.0 249476  1552 ?        Sl   Oct06   0:00 rsyslogd -c5
root       483  0.0  0.0  21604   848 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       484  0.0  0.0  21604   848 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       565  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       570  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 [kworker/3:2]
root       580  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [ttm_swap]
root       639  0.0  0.0  15196   400 ?        S    Oct06   0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
root       720  0.0  0.0  50040  2924 ?        Ss   Oct06   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root       803  0.0  0.0  15792   976 tty4     Ss+  Oct06   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root       816  0.0  0.0  15792   972 tty5     Ss+  Oct06   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
root       827  0.0  0.0  15792   968 tty2     Ss+  Oct06   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root       828  0.0  0.0  15792   972 tty3     Ss+  Oct06   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root       831  0.0  0.0  15792   976 tty6     Ss+  Oct06   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
root       834  0.0  0.0   4336   712 ?        Ss   Oct06   0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
root       840  0.0  0.0  19120  1044 ?        Ss   Oct06   0:00 cron
daemon     841  0.0  0.0  16916   372 ?        Ss   Oct06   0:00 atd
bind       896  0.0  0.3 384688 15180 ?        Ssl  Oct06   0:00 /usr/sbin/named -u bind
root       908  0.0  0.0  15988   696 ?        Ss   Oct06   0:08 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
mysql     1011  0.0  1.3 1083280 55392 ?       Ssl  Oct06   0:20 /usr/sbin/mysqld
whoopsie  1016  0.0  0.1 187668  4080 ?        Ssl  Oct06   0:00 whoopsie
root      1039  0.0  0.1  93804  4692 ?        S    Oct06   1:02 /usr/sbin/vmtoolsd
proftpd   1076  0.0  0.0  94700  2148 ?        Ss   Oct06   0:00 proftpd: (accepting connections)
root      1373  0.0  0.5  87952 22660 ?        Ss   Oct06   0:02 /usr/bin/perl /usr/share/webmin/miniserv.pl /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf
root      1376  0.0  0.0  15792   972 tty1     Ss+  Oct06   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
root      1420  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Oct06   0:00 [kworker/u9:1]
root      8889  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:32   0:00 [kworker/u8:0]
root      9267  0.0  0.0  73444  3672 ?        Rs   08:51   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0
root      9434  0.0  0.1  22840  4152 pts/0    Ss   08:51   0:00 -bash
root      9517  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:53   0:00 [kworker/u8:2]
root      9942  0.0  0.2 195700  8696 ?        Ss   09:12   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9947  0.0  0.1 195732  5228 ?        S    09:12   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9948  0.0  0.1 195732  5228 ?        S    09:12   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9949  0.0  0.1 195732  5228 ?        S    09:12   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9950  0.0  0.1 195732  5228 ?        S    09:12   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9951  0.0  0.1 195732  5228 ?        S    09:12   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     10047  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:16   0:00 [kworker/u8:1]
root     10095  0.0  0.0  18164  1268 pts/0    R+   09:21   0:00 ps aux
```

Comment: The port seems to listen but you still have no access to it. Have you looked in the local firewal (iptables -nL)?

Comment: Thanks @SteffenNielsen, I've try to flush the firewall, and its working. it's the local firewall that make the web server timeout. But the firewall rule is appearing on it's own. When i reboot it, it dissapear. And then appear the next day again. Is it a normal thing?

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu on it's own will block ports. Instead applications like fail2ban would be able to do that, but i don't seem to find any of those applications from your process list. It could be a cron job of some sort.

Comment: @SteffenNielsen, you're right. Currently there is apf on the cron job daily. Thank you.
when i try to run the apf manually, the web server got timeout. 
as I search the apf, it's for security related. 
btw Is the apf misconfigured or it's the default behaviour and need to be configured?

Comment: perhaps you could paste the content of the cron job in your question too?

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response, @SteffenNielsen the cron job just stop and start the apf service. 
/etc/apf/apf -f >> /dev/null 2>&1
/etc/apf/apf -s >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: I can't really tell what is wrong here, and I'm not so familiar with APF. To begin with, I would deactivate/uncomment the cron job till you find a solution.